# How can I end a session in Meteor

Tags: javascript, bash, mongodb, meteor

The meteor books I'm reading now all just say use CTRL + ALT + C to quit meteor in the terminal, but sometimes even when you have done that, or closed the terminal that meteor project was running in, it is still running on port 3000. My question is, and I'm sure there's a simple answer, but **how can I kill this process in meteor?**. There's no man pages, and --help provides no solution. I could find the process ID and kill it, but there's got to be a better Meteor solution, and that's what I'm looking for. Sorry if it's a dumb question, I just can't find an answer out there. Thx :)

Comment: What version of meteor are you running?

Comment: I am running Meteor 0.9.4 currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the case, but you can simply type Ctrl+C in terminal and application should exit.

Comment: Not always reliable. Sometimes your not even in a terminal and it's running. That's why I specifically stated **other than CTRL + ALT + C**.

Comment: And this isn't CTRL ALT C, I've never had problem you asked, after Ctrl+C my applications always exit so I can't help you further